# Twitter icon upside-down

Tags: copyright, trademark

If I use Twitter icon upside-down as my site favicon, will it be a copyright/trademark violation?

I have copywriting slogan "Down with Twitter" among others on my site.

Comment: or overstriken Twitter icon?

Comment: look up the history of the "The South Butt" company

Comment: I vote to close. The question asks for specific legal advice, which is expressly off-topic. See the help file here: https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...will it be a copyright/trademark violation?

You'll find out when Twitter threatens to sue, or does sue you. How much money do you have to defend yourself?

The court (judge or jury) will decide if your usage infringes and dilutes Twitter's business and trademark, or not. Or, if you claim usage of the upside down icon is a parody, the court will decide if indeed your usage could be viewed as a parody by the public.

You might win.

Comment: and if I overstrike Twitter icon with a red line, can it be considered as anything other than a parody?

Comment: That's up to the courts.